# Azure media services encryption in transit and at rest

Tags: encryption, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I want to enable encryption in transit and encryption at rest for all the content stored in media storage. 
As I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-concepts),

> No encryption is used. This is the default value. When using this
>   option your content is not protected in transit or at rest in storage.

But since all my data resides in storage itself, won't it be encrypted by default at rest because of the [SSE in Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption) ? Am I missing something here ? Also, how is the metadata (Asset information, Locator information etc.) about the content stored ?

Answer (score 0):

with Media Services v2, you can use AssetCreationOptions.StorageEncrypted option, as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-dotnet-upload-files#upload-files-using-net-sdk-extensions.

See, the "Storage side encryption" table for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-rest-storage-encryption#considerations

Please, let us know if you have other questions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Juliako, but my question was more around the underlying motive of having this AssetCreationOptions.StorageEncrypted option, as the corresponding storage account already has this by default.